# What is the best way to convert a garage to livable space?

Tags: insulation, heating, garage, cooling

Garage Conversion

We have an attached garage that has finished walls with no insulation, angled roof with no insulation and exposed rafters, and a new roll up uninsulated garage door. It has a side door that leads to the backyard. Our central AC just died, and we are replacing, but considering running new duct out to the garage so our large family can use the space. It seems expensive. The temperature here is extreme in summer and winter, 106 and below 40. I just don't think a window unit will make it livable if we leave the door open from the main house to the garage. What's a mom to do? Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This seems like a pretty broad question, but adding some more details (e.g. pictures) might help. If you can't edit in the pictures, edit in URLs of pictures and someone will be along to edit the pictures in.

Comment: Since you are replacing A/C, consider adding enough capacity to support the garage (by the way, how would you heat it?).  Consider locating the condenser on the shady (north or northeast) side of the house to save energy.  Consider going with a ground-sourced heat pump if water access and electricity prices make that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

An uninsulated space will be a huge energy waster. Expensive yes, you would need to have the walls insulated, the roof structure insulated and finished, as well as the door rollup door insulated. If you plan to never use it as a garage again, the door can be removed and a wall put in its place. Some people even build a portion of the garage into a shed in the front, to keep the door. Other things to consider are the floor, cold in winter, hot in summer. But there are lots of things that can be e done to convert a garage. Depends on how much money you want to spend, how much you want to convert, if you plan to ever use it as a garage again...